# ActiveRecord regular-expression search by whole word

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, regex, activerecord, sql-like

I want to search ActiveRecord model `Product` by keyword, but I only want to match whole words in its `description` instead of arbitrary substrings.

Say I have the string

```
'the packaging May Vary'
```

as a `Product`'s `description`, then a search using keyword `'aging'` **should not** match, but a search for `'packaging'` **should** match. So match by words, beginning or end of the string. I want to do something like this:

```
Product.where("description ~* ?", "Regexp")
```

What should I replace the Regexp with, something like `"%[^|| ]#{string}[$|| ]%"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.where("description ~* ?", "\m#{string}\M")
```

`\m` matches only at the beginning of a word and `\M` matches only at the end of a word. More info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html